# Flutter App freezes in native Splash/Loading-Screen

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies, citrix

I and my team have a really frustrating problem for weeks now.

### Problem in short

The newest version of our flutter app wrapped again by Citrix MDX is not able to continue running beyond its native implemented Splash Screen. It does not crash.

---

### How I got there

I shipped a Flutter app as an IPA file build with Flutter 1.17.5. The file itself can be installed on any iOS device and runs fine. The IPA-file-receiver tried the same and it runs fine too.

The IPA-receiver wraps&signs the app again with his provisioning profile and certificate using Citrix MDX (Version > 20.x). Only the local MDX tool via command-line (not the online) is able to wrap the app. The log file from the MDX tool does not contain any errors.

The wrapped-app can be installed on their iOS devices and run.

**Result:** The native Splash-Screen is shown and that's it. The app does not continue to show the first Flutter view nor does it crash or close itself.

Unfortunately, we have no OS logs from the running app and also we don't have the wrapped-app from the MDX tool.

**What makes me wonder:** ...is that the wrapped app from MDX works on iOS tablets after changing its orientation this will somehow trigger Flutter to load its first view.

---

### What we already did

- try-catch'ed the main-Method and provided a Flutter-Screen with some Error-Output capability. **Result:** The error screen showed that some plugin we are using via pubspec was missing. However, the MDX tool logs showed that the plugin was there. Worth mentioning: The error screen did not showed up in our latest test, the app was just somehow freezing in its native Splash-Screen again.
- Searching for any changes since the last release that was running fine.

---

Is there anyone who has some idea worth trying out or some hint where you would start searching for the problem?

Help is much appreciated and sorry for not having some re-produceable steps.

Comment: Would it be possible that somehow the MDX links some libs not in the correct way? Could the App be stoping in its native part, because some libs from Flutter or dependencies are missing?